# Notation: How to write sum up to ceiling

Tags: notation

I have the following formula:

$$SR(x) =\sum_{a \in Ax}\frac{SR(a)}{2}+\sum_{v \in Vx} SR(v)$$

SR(x) is on a scale of of 0 to 1, and the values of each $\sum_{a \in Ax}\frac{SR(a)}{2}$ and $\sum_{v \in Vx} SR(v)$ can only reach a ceiling of 0.5 along that scale.

How do I show that ceiling in the formula?

Comment: Are you able to just use the ceiling symbols $\lceil x \rceil$?

Comment: I'm an utter beginner at math notation. I've read about the ceiling symbol, but I'm just not quite sure how to apply that in this context.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do with the ceiling function? I'm not totally sure what you mean about the scales and stuff.

Comment: Be glad to. The value of SR(x) is between 0 and 1, and it is a sum of elements within two sets A and V. The total sum of each set has a maximum value of 0.5. Let me know if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know that there is dedicated notation for that, however ...

> SR(x) is on a scale of of 0 to 1, and the values of each $\sum_{a \in Ax}\frac{SR(a)}{2}$ and $\sum_{v \in Vx} SR(v)$ can only reach a ceiling of 0.5 along that scale.

... If you have otherwise established that $\;\sum_{a \in Ax}\frac{SR(a)}{2} \le 0.5\;$ and $\;\sum_{v \in Vx} SR(v) \le 0.5\,$ then...

> How do I show that ceiling in the formula?

... You could make that crystal clear using a(n abuse of) notation like:

$$\underbrace{SR(x)}_{\le 1} = \underbrace{\sum_{a \in Ax}\frac{SR(a)}{2}}_{\le 0.5}+\underbrace{\sum_{v \in Vx} SR(v)}_{\le 0.5}$$